# JSON formatting issue

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using JSON.NET to create a JSON string. Basically, I have three `List` objects that contain information I retrieve from a database. Each list contains information about companies at a certain level of partnership (gold, silver, and bronze). I need my web method to return this JSON string where each partnership level is a sub level of the string, with each of those companies and their information listed within that sub level. I tried using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` for each of my lists. The issue with this is that I need to have sub levels in my JSON string, as seen below:

```
{
  "gold": {
            //each gold level company
            { "name": name, "logo": logo, ... },
            { "name": name, "logo": logo, ... },
            ...
          },
 "silver": { ... },
 "bronze": { ... }
}
```

Can someone give me some tips on the best way to achieve this using JSON.NET?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

```
var json  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                new { gold = goldList, silver = silverList, bronze = bronzeList });
```

where `goldList`, `silverList` and `bronzeList` are your lists.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. I'll give this a shot when I get back to my machine. Do the `gold`, `silver`, and `bronze` in your code represent what gets printed out as the heading for each sub level?